# Remove vertical space between paragraphs for IEEEtran class for conference

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, ieeetran

I am using IEEEtran latex class 2-column format for conference. It gives me spacing between paragraphs which I want to take off.

I got the template from this link.

http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic: Please use `ieeeconf` for conferences. Recently, every conference provides a copy of the custom `ieeeconf.cls` otherwise you can download it from IEEE or CTAN

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about "spacing between paragraphs which I want to take off". Ideally, you would post a Minimum Working Example (MWE) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix. Incidentally, a quick check compiling a dummy-text document with either the IEEEconf or the IEEEtran document class doesn't reveal any unusual spacing issues. Hence the request for an MWE so that we can get a start on what's afflicting your document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I met exactly the same problem using `IEEEtran` for two-columns conference paper. Downloading the latest version of [`IEEEtran.cls` from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) and replacing the original one solved my problem.

The version of `IEEEtran` in the ZIP file is

```
%% IEEEtran.cls 2011/11/03 version V1.8 based on
%% IEEEtran.cls 2007/03/05 version V1.7a
```

and the counterpart in the CTAN is

```
%% IEEEtran.cls 2012/12/27 version V1.8
```

There are many (non)trivial changes between these two versions. Hope it also works for you.